# Guzzle difference between 'connect_timeout' and 'timeout'

Tags: guzzle

What's the difference between 'connect_timeout' and 'timeout' request options in Guzzle.

Answer (score 30):

The most basic way I can explain this is (from what I understand):

- **connect_timeout** - Time Guzzle will wait to establish a connection to the server
- **timeout** - Time Guzzle will wait, once a connection has been made, for the server to handle the request. For example waiting on a long running script.

Also this answer relating to curl's timeouts is quite nice - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94604/does-curl-have-a-timeout/94612

The flags that get used to define the timeouts, --connect-timeout and --max-time, make the difference a lot clearer.

I also believe the Guzzle options are linked to these curl options

- **timeout** - https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.html
- **connect_timeout** -
  https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT.html